# Aplicar eventos jQuery a elemntos HTML generados dinamicamente

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Me encuentro en un dilema, lo que pasa es que tengo una página en la cual, cuando se carga, aparece en un principio un recuadro que imprime el mensaje **"Nada para mostrar"**, después de unos segundos se generan elementos `html` con el contenido que se debe mostrar allí.

El problema es que no he podido aplicar eventos de `jQuery` a estos elementos que se generan después de que carga la página. Por ejemplo si deseo que al dar click en un elemento me muestre un alerta no funciona, pero si hago un `console.log` que muestre un mensaje cuando cargue la página si funciona, es decir el archivo se esta llamando correctamente.

La forma en la que aplico el evento es la siguiente:

```
$('.Sheduler_Header').click(function(){
        alert('Hola');
    });
$('.Sheduler_Header').on('click',function() {
    alert("dasdsadsa");
    console.log("dasjkhdkalsd");
});

console.log("Hola 2");
```

Lo intente de esas dos formas y no muestra el alerta.

Cómo puedo generar estos eventos a elementos que se generan después de cargar la página?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes que englobar esas funciones en un scope màs generalizado, el onready de Jquery, es similar a esto

```
$( () => {
  ...
});
```

Yo te recomendarìa que le pidieras al DOM que este al pendiente de los eventos, no a los propios selectores, en mi experiencia a veces fallan si le dices directo al selector que estè pendiente del click, entonces tu còdigo quedarìa algo asì

```
$( () => {

  $(document).on('click', '.Sheduler_Header', function() {
    alert('Le diste click');
  });

});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Alberto funciono.